# Would like explanation on the not equal(!=) filter condition in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter the records from dataframe that not equals(!=) values from multiple columns.
I am able to make it work but having trouble in interpreting the way the filter works..

#### Problem Statement

- Dataframe with id and value column
- Filter only records that does not have
  id = 1 and value = 'Value1'

I am able to solve the problem using below code

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[4]")    
val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()    
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq((1, "Value1"),(2, "Value2"), (3, "Value3"), (4, "Value1"), (5, "Value2"), (6, "Value3")).toDF("id", "value")    
df.filter("(id != 1 or value != 'Value1')").show
```

#### Output with "OR":

```
+---+------+
| id| value|
+---+------+
|  2|Value2|
|  3|Value3|
|  4|Value1|
|  5|Value2|
|  6|Value3|
+---+------+
```

#### Output with "AND":

It is removing the another record with id = 4 and value = Value1.. Basically it is removing the all the records with value != Value1.

```
+---+------+
| id| value|
+---+------+
|  2|Value2|
|  3|Value3|
|  5|Value2|
|  6|Value3|
+---+------+
```

#### Question:

Initially i was trying with "AND" condition inside filter like `"df.filter("(id != 1 and value != 'Value1')").show"` but it did not work

My understanding is since it is combination of two condition`(id not equal 1 and value not equal Value1)` and hence it should be `AND`
but strangely it works with `OR` condition inside filter.

Can someone explain this behaviour and how should interpret this. Sry if this is SQL syntax question

Comment: Updated the answer to include "AND" output.. Per my understanding, AND condition is working like "OR" and vice versa inside filter

Comment: May i know why this question is down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement would logically be interpreted

```
not (id = 1 and value = 'Value1')
```

And you'd expect this to return all rows not matching both values together. The grouping is important

That statement can be logically translated to

```
id!=1 or value!="Value1"
```

This is called [De Morgans Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), and explains what you're seeing

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this in Java (and similar in Python, Scala),

```
ds = ds.filter(functions.not(functions.col(colName).isin(exclusionSet)).
filter(functions.not(functions.col(colName).isin(exclusionSet2));
```

and then keep on adding as many filters as you need.

functions.not method excludes the specified set of values. .isin method accepts any Object or Seq, so you can specify multiple values.